# How can I clean up this FactoryGirl build strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

My tests are currently working with this strategy, but there is probably a cleaner way of doing this. Any help in approaching this more intelligently would be appreciated.

I have two setup two Factories

```
factory :story do
  title       { Faker::Name.title }
  link        { Faker::Internet.url }
  teaser_text { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
  author
  issue
  source
  headline
end
```

and

```
factory :headline do
  featured          false
  featured_story_id 1
  issue_id          1
end
```

A story belongs to a headline
A headline has_many stories and belongs_to a featured_story (which is a story)
I have a not_null constraint on the featured_story_id column

Here is what I am currently doing in my rspec test to create a headline

```
3.times do
  story = build(:story, issue: Issue.unpublished.first)
  story.headline.update(featured_story: story, issue: story.issue)
end
```

Of course would I'd prefer is to just say

```
create_list(:story, 3)
```

and let the factory work it out.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to use *FactoryGirl's* [after(:create)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) callback to populate a story's `headline` attribute:

```
factory :story do
  ...

  after(:create) do |story|
    story.headline.update(featured_story: story, issue: story.issue)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I played around with the after(:create), but what I run into is that I end up with two headlines. The story has to create a headline and then it creates another one on the after create. So the test passes, but I've got some junk data.

Comment: That was an oversight in my part. There was absolutely no need to create a new headline. I've updated the answer.